# XmlReader and IDisposable

Tags: .net-2.0, idisposable, xmlreader

Perhaps my eyes are fooling me, but how is it that in .NET 2.0, XmlReader implements Dispose but does not have a Dispose() method? I see it has Dispose(bool), but not a parameterless overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implements it explicitly System.IDisposable.Dispose().  Dispose(boolean) is a normal method that does this ...

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.ReadState != ReadState.Closed)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple I had just glossed over.

Answer (score 1):

... so you need to call it for ex. this way

```
    XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(s);
    ((IDisposable)r).Dispose();
```

Comment: A using block works too, because it implicitly casts to IDisposable.

Comment: ...I suppose I shouldn't have used the word "implicit," given the context of the conversation.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that calling the .Close() method will serve the same purpose?